# Como passar a referência de um objeto?

Tags: delphi, lista, referência

Eu estou tentando passar a referência de um objeto que está em uma lista para outra lista, sem precisar deletar o objeto e atualizando a primeira lista para que o objeto não fique mais referênciado nela.

O codigo está dentro de uma *thread*, mas quando eu tento passar a referência do objeto e deletar da lista ocorre algum erro e a lista não atualiza corretamente os objetos.

Segue o código:

```
tthread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
      if (ListaSala.Count < LimiteSala) and (ListaPessoas.Count > 0) then
      begin
        ListaSala.Add(ListaPessoas.Extract);
        ListaPessoas.Items[ListaPessoas.Count-1] := nil;
        ListaPessoas.Delete(ListaPessoas.Count-1);
        if ListaSala.Count > 0 then
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ListaSala.Items[ListaSala.Count-1].NomeToString() + ' entrou na sala');
     end;
     Label5.Text := ListaSala.Count.ToString;
  end);
sleep(2*Segundo);
```

Alguma luz?

Comment: O extract não retira logo o item da lista? Esse set a nil e delete da ListaPessoas é mesmo necessario?

Comment: tentou usar TObject ?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você terá que usar `ForceQueue` em lugar de `Queue`, observando também que provavelmente você terá que usar `Synchronize` nessa sua procedure anônima, já que está atualizando listas externas à thread. Talvez você deva considerar criar um instância de thread mesmo, completa, e não uma thread anônima, pois você terá mais recursos para editar suas listas e poderá passá-las com `var` nos parâmetros do `constructor` da thread.